# PHP not editing text file?

Tags: php, file, editing

ive got this bit of PHP code here which has previously worked fine when opening and editing a .txt file, however the code is no longer working. Can anyone explain whats going on and the solution if possible? What this code should be doing is allowing the user to enter a name, and a name the user wants to replace within a text file, however this is not whats happening, the code appears to run fine, however it does not edit the document.

```
<form method="post" 
      name="change_name and surname"
      action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> <!--call the php within this page-->

        Name:
        <input name="Name" type="text" id="sname" />
        <br /><br />            

        Names to Replace:
        <input name="Names" type="text" id="sname" />
        <br /><br />    

        Surname:
        <input name="Surname" type="text" id="name" />
        <br /><br />

        Surnames to Replace:
        <input name="Surnames" type="text" id="name" />
        <br /><br />    

      <input type="submit" value="Submitt" />


</form> 


<?PHP
//must have input form to get the data from the user
if (!empty($_POST['Name'])&& !empty($_POST['Surname'])&&($_POST['Names'])&& !empty($_POST['Surnames']))

    {
        //store value to the local variable
        $Name = $_POST['Name'];// original name which is has been added to the add2.php file//
        $Names = $_POST['Names'];// replacement for the name//
        $Surname = $_POST['Surname'];
        $Surnames = $_POST['Surnames'];

        $fullname = $Name. " " .$Surname ;
        $fullname2 = $Names. " " .$Surnames ;
        $file = "names.txt";// manufacture1.txt is the file where it has been used manipulate the name and surname replacement//

        $haystack =  file($file);// manipulates the data using  "a" append as saved the name and surname in first step and changed using t 

        for($i=0; $i < count($haystack); $i++)//$i < count means i is greater than count//

        {
                $haystack[$i] = str_ireplace($fullname, $fullname2, $haystack[$i]); // haystack has been to used to loop//
        }       

        file_put_contents($file, $haystack);
    }

else{
    echo"<b>Please input Name and Surname !!</b>";// will ask the user to input their name and surname//
}


?>
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're performing replacements line-by-line rather than just reading in the whole file and performing a single replacement?

Comment: not particularly, just found it easier to set it up like this at the time I originally created it.

Comment: Well it's horribly inefficient...

Comment: Please check the permission of the ```names.txt``` and make sure it is writable.

Comment: so i found out the problem wasn't with the code at all, it was an error with the text file